# Log transformation uses

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, predictive-models, econometrics, logarithm

I am trying to understand how the migration of a male member affects the number of hours spent by left-behind women in various agricultural and non-agricultural activities. I used a simple OLS model with the coefficient coming out to be very small. Instead of relying on the magnitude of the coefficient, I plan to mainly look at the direction of change that is, increase or decrease in the number of hours spent by left-behind women.

Just to be sure about the direction of change, I took a log transformation of the number of hours. Now , first, how do I interpret the coefficient? I think the coefficient will give me the percentage change in hours spent with migration.
Please confirm if my interpretation is correct.

Second , is it okay to use log transformation in this sense?

Comment: You don't need to make a log transformation to be sure about the direction of change, although if you have a few outliers in the number of hours, it will help reduce their influence on the estimate.

Comment: What was you reason for taking the log in the first place?